# Python reading from a text file

Tags: python, dictionary, text-files

I am trying to read from a text file and store it into a dictionary. My text file contains values like:

```
G314889730  4.3
G944177112  4.3
G383969021  4.3
G631050911  4.3
G424860434  4.3
G424860434  4.3
G537477205  NA
```

But I am getting an empty dictionary in the end.

```
file = open("myfile","r")
HKH = {}
for line in file:
    x = line.split()
    if len(x)>2:
       GID = x[0]
       CRR = x[1]
       HKH[GID] = CRR
       print (HKH[GID])
```

Comment: try testing `if len(x) >= 2:` instead. is it still empty then?

Comment: Test with `if not line.strip(): continue` before assigning to  `x`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your condition should be `len(x) >= 2`. `x` will have two elements if there's data on the row.

Comment: It works but I have 96 items in my file. It is storing only 80! Any ideas why?

Comment: put an `else` after the `if` and print the lines that do not get saved. look at them, find out what's wrong.

Comment: Duplicates ..Sorry didn't notice them!

Comment: @VarunYadav No problem. Happens to everyone, that's what debugging is for.

Answer (score 2):

Try to stick to the Python best practices:

```
HKH = {}
with open("myfile","r") as file:
    for line in file:
        try:
            GID, CRR = line.strip().split()
        except ValueError:
            continue
        else:
            HKG[GID] = CRR
```

- Open files in a with block -> you don't have to deal with closing the files
- Try the parsing first, and if it doesn't work, handle the error.

Comment: Might also `strip()` the line before splitting it and only execute the last line if `CRR` is a string

Answer (score 0):

if data is in this format "G314889730  4.3", when you split it you will get the list of length 2, so use (==) instead of (>)

```
file = open("myfile","r")
for line in lines:
    x = line.split()
    if len(x)==2:
       GID = x[0]
       CRR = x[1]
       HKH[GID] = CRR
       print (HKH[GID])
```

Comment: Your answer is also correct!

Comment: mark it as an answer :p

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
final_data = dict([i.strip('\n').split() for i in open('filename.txt')])
```